# Apache + mod_wsgi - Python doesn't load installed modules

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, pip, mod-wsgi

I have an Apache server with mod_wsgi, running an Python 2.7 script.
The script uses the python Pillow module, installed via pip.

Running the script normally using `python script.py` works okay, but when running the script from wsgi - An ImportError exception is thrown for PIL.

This is the Apache configuration from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python/wsgi.py

        <Directory "/home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There's no virtualenv installed, and there's just one Python installation on this machine.

What can I do to make python find its installed modules?

I've seen solutions around the same ballpark that use mod_wsgi's [daemon mode](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html?highlight=daemon#embedded-or-daemon-mode) to manually define python path. Is there a way to do so in embedded mode?

EDIT:
Apache error log:

```
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931400 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223] mod_wsgi (pid=48202): Target WSGI script '/home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931475 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223] mod_wsgi (pid=48202): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python/wsgi.py'., referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931557 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223]   File "/home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931687 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223]     import sprites, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931705 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223]   File "/home/nitay/Desktop/WebsitePath/Python/sprites.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931767 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223]     from PIL import Image, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
[Wed Nov 02 16:08:02.931830 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 48202:tid 140100207392512] [client 192.168.1.179:29223] ImportError: No module named PIL, referer: http://192.168.1.247/index.html
```

sys.path & version for the normal Python and WSGI:

```
Normal:
>>> sys.version
'2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) \n[GCC 5.3.1 20160413]'
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/nitay/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']

WSGI:
>>> sys.version
2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) [GCC 5.3.1 20160413] 
>>> sys.path
['/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib
```

Comment: I would compate `sys.version` and `sys.path` when you run normally and from wsgi.

Comment: Show the full error message and traceback from the Apache error log.

Comment: Also explain why you want to use embedded mode? Using daemon mode is the preferred setup anyway.

Comment: I'd like to use embedded mode because mod_wsgi works, and setting up mod_wsgi was not a smooth process - many things broke on the way. I would like to focus on the software side of this project, but if needed - Daemon mode it it. Why is it the preferred setup?

Comment: It seems that mod_wsgi runs python as su, and when running python as su the path does not include any site-packages folder.

Comment: No, mod_wsgi doesn't run as super user (su). Apache starts as root but then drops down to an unprivileged account. Nothing to do with Python should run as root.

Answer (score 7):

in my case, the modules were installed in a user env, vs the machine's env.
i just run:

```
sudo -H pip3.7 install mako
```

The `-H` says to `sudo` to install the module in the root machine directory vs user directory who run the command ...

this is because Apache cannot access/read personal user's files.

Answer (score 3):

I redid the server configuration, this time naming things properly, used virtualenv, and Daemon mode to wsgi.

Here's the apache configuration I ended up with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        WSGIDaemonProcess sprites-toolbox python-path=/home/nitay/Desktop/SpritesToolbox/Python:/home/nitay/Desktop/SpritesToolbox/Python/sprite-toolbox-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup sprites-toolbox

        WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /home/nitay/Desktop/SpritesToolbox/Python/wsgi.py


        <Directory "/home/nitay/Desktop/SpritesToolbox/Python">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Moral of the story? "Time is precious, waste it wisely" (Don't half-ass server configurations)

Comment: Best practice is not to add ``site-packages`` in ``python-path``. Use the ``python-home`` option to specify location of virtual environment. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this and the discussion above really helped. My solution however, was simply to set up the Python path at the beginning of my WSGI program, e.g.:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    import sys
    path = "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/"
    if path not in sys.path: sys.path.append(path)
```

Comment: You should not do that in ``application()`` call. Also, adding that path suggests your mod_wsgi is more than likely not compiled for the Python installation you are trying to use. There should never be a need to add the Python installations ``site-packages`` directory explicitly. I would suggest you will possibly encounter other issues if mixing Python installations.

Comment: Hard to disagree with you except that there appear to be problems with Amazon Linux and WSGI as discussed by others elsewhere. Never encountered this issue with Centos in many versions. I have no idea if wsgi as installed with yum on Amazon Linux is compiled for it or not. This works and doesn't involve changes to the Apache configuration ... YMMV.

Comment: Sounds like they might provide you a custom mod_wsgi compiled against Python 2.7 installed under ``/usr/local``, but still have a separate system Python installed under ``/usr``. If that is the case, they should set ``WSGIPythonHome /usr/local`` in the Apache configuration otherwise it will use Python installation files under ``/usr`` which may cause a range of problems if the version isn't exactly the same.

Comment: I tried that, thanks, but it didn't work. Google'ing shows this is a known problem. Given that all my WSGI software starts at the same point and returns there when it's finished gives me no anxiety that the path will somehow get lost. Because I'm also having possibly similar problems with Certbot, my solution is going to be to revert to Centos, which is my normal choice - there is enough work to be getting on with to lose time messing around with OS problems. Thanks for your help.