# Numpy - Internal Server Error on Apache

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Flask app on EC2 (Ubuntu) so I can use a predictive model I have created to send two data points to from another system. Everything works fine without numpy, but as soon as I add it back in Apache throws an internal server error. All modules have been installed and verified with pip --freeze. The app lives in a directory named flaskapp.

Here is the code from my wsgi:

import sys

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')
from flaskapp import app as application
```

Here are the changes Ive made to the Apache conf file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and here is the Flask app code:

```
#imports
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pickle as pickle

#Open Predicitve Model
pklmodel = 'model.pkl'
my_model = pickle.dumps(pklmodel, protocol=2)
app = Flask(__name__)

#Flask App Endpoint
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])

#Predicitions Function
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    predict_request = [data['Temp'],data['Pressure']]
    predict_request = np.array(predict_request)
    predGhi = my_model.predict(predict_request)
    output = [predGhi[0]]
    return jsonify(results=output)

#run app as webservice
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache + mod\_wsgi - Python doesn't load installed modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391409/apache-mod-wsgi-python-doesnt-load-installed-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an Internal Server Error, there should be a record in Apache's error log. Most probably, there's an uncaught exception and there'll be its stacktrace there. See [Debugging Techniques — mod_wsgi 4.5.16 documentation](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html).

> When using mod_wsgi, unless you or the web framework you are using
>   takes specific action to catch exceptions and present the details in
>   an alternate manner, the only place that details of uncaught
>   exceptions will be recorded is in the Apache error log files. The
>   Apache error log files are therefore your prime source of information
>   when things go wrong.

A `mod_wsgi` error log entry on a user request [looks something like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/236131/apache-mod-wsgi-django-strange-500-errors):

```
[error] [client ..] mod_wsgi (pid=8184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '.../django.wsgi'.
[error] [client ..] Traceback (most recent call last):
<...>
[error] [client ..] File "../apps/py26_logging/handlers.py", line 394, in emit
[error] [client ..]   self.stream.flush()
[error] [client ..] ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

If it's without `[client]`, this means the error occurred on loading/unloading the module (e.g. a compilation error).

Comment: Thanks - I checked there first, but rechecked again just now and it states that there is no module named numpy, but yet it is installed and pip freeze indicates such.

Comment: @DataGuy well, check your `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks - all of my other modules are working fine - Ill check the sys.path specifically for numpy.